# How to set a value in a select from an object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, model

I'm new to Angular so please be gentle :)

I am recieving a "Brand" Object from the server and I want to set the select field with the good corresponding value.

Brands look like this :

```
Brands = [{name: "BRAND1", id=242},
          {name: "BRAND2", id=562}]
```

And I got from the server:

```
brandFromTheServer = {name: "BRAND2", id=562};
```

This is my select :

```
<select id="brand" ng-model="product.brand" class="form-control" ng-options="brand as brand.name for brand in brands"></select>
```

And I want the select to be set with brandFromTheServer.

I tried in the controller:

```
$scope.product.brand = brandFromTheServer;
```

How can I set the value of the select with the brand that I'm recieving ?

Sorry, my English is terrible !
Please help :=)

Comment: what is your selected value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
   <select ng-options="option.name for option in advertiserList" ng-model="selectedOption.advertiserChoice" class="form-control"></select>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.advertiserList = response.advertisers;
            var data = $scope.advertiserList.getIndexBy("id",  $scope.currentAdvertiser.id)
            $scope.selectedOption.advertiserChoice = $scope.advertiserList[data];
```

The method getIndexBy() is like this:

```
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
              if (this[i][name] === value) {
                  return i;
              }
          }
      }
```

And my advertiserList json looks like this:

```
"advertisers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Somebody Franck",

    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Me Me me",

    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try something like this !

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="brand" ng-model="product.brand" class="form-control" ng-     options="brand as brand.name for brand in brands">
   <option value="o">Val 1</option>
   <option value="1">Val 2</option>
   <option value="2">Val 3</option>
</select>
```

$scope.product.brand = 0 or 1 or 2;

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct when using ng-options, however the `product.brand` is not bound to the Brand object. Something like this works:

Controller:

```
$scope.brands = [
    {
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      name: '2'
    },{
      name: '3'
    }

  ];

  $scope.product = {
    brand: $scope.brands[1] // now it has a 'reference'
  };
```

Comment: Thanks ! Using brand: $scope.brands[1] updates the select, I'll try something like this :)